# Fluent interface by chaining AJAX promises?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, fluent-interface

I am trying to achieve the below API for queuing AJAX promises to execute later. I do not understand how I can pass multiple promises up the chain. Here is where I want to be if possible:

```
MyObj.ancestor(99)
    .parent(98)
    .child(97)
    .done(function (resp) {...}
```

Can I pass ancestor's promise to parent, then to pass it down to child, and finally to 'done' in that order?

Comment: $.when is similar if you don't care about the order, but in this case order matters.

Comment: Are `parent` and `child` supposed to be synchronous, or do they create their own promises? Do they need to wait for their `ancestor`s promise to resolve?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [Combining promises and chaining](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26837334/1048572) which was asked only 20min later. Isn't it?

Comment: @TruMan, you need to understand the distinction between "passing a promise down a chain" (which is not a particularly useful concept) and "forming a promise chain" (which is both useful and very special). Promise chains are formed with promise methods, most notably `.then()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining promises and chaining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837334/combining-promises-and-chaining)

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can, but that would require adding a lot of very specific and not too useful otherwise methods to MyObj and it would also not really use promises - but rather custom chaining.

Alternatively, if all the methods return promises - you can do something like:

```
MyObj.ancestor(99).then(function(result){
    return MyObj.parent(98);
}).then(function(result){
    return MyObj.child(97)
}).done(function(resp){
    ...
});
```