# Combining promises and chaining

Tags: javascript, promise, chaining, method-chaining, bluebird

Is there a good design pattern for utilizing promises, while still supporting chaining? For example, let's say that we have something like:

```
function Foobar() {
  this.foo = function() {
    console.log('foo');
    return this;
  };

  this.bar = function () {
    console.log('bar');
    return this;
  };
}

var foobar = new Foobar();
foobar.foo().bar();
```

If instead we change the methods to use promises, e.g.

```
function Foobar() {
  this.foo = function() {
    var self = this;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      console.log('foo');
      resolve(self);
    });
  };
  ...
}
```

Is there a good way to do something like:

```
var foobar = new Foobar();
foobar.foo().bar().then(function () {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for `Promise.all`?

Comment: You can't return both `this` for chaining purposes and return a promise unless you make your own object into a promise also (which has some uses, but isn't usually a good approach).  So you would typically pick one or the other to return for a particular method.  Methods that start an async operation and thus create a promise would return the promise.  Other methods that didn't have another return value would return `this` for chaining purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If instead we change the methods to use promises, e.g.
>
> ```
> this.foo = function() {
>   var self = this;
>   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
>     …
>     resolve(self);
>   });
> };
> ```

I would recommend not to do that. This just begs for trouble. If your instance (or: its modification) is the result of your computation, then what is the state of your object (I assume you use OOP to encapsulate state) during that computation? What happened if this (or any other) method is called from a different <s>process (thread)</s> turn of the event loop? You'd have to go down the entire rabbit hole…

Try to use functional programming as far as you can.

> Is there a good way to do something like:
>
> ```
> new Foobar().foo().bar().then(function () {
>   // do something
> });
> ```

Yes, but you'd have to use `.then` after every invocation:

```
new Foobar().foo().then(function(foobar) {
  return foobar.bar();
}).then(function(barresult) {
  // do something
});
```

The Bluebird library (as do some others) even has a utility function for that [`.call()`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#callstring-propertyname--dynamic-arg---promise). So you'd do

```
new Foobar().foo().call("bar").then(function(barresult) {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that OP should not use promises for a sync task. Other than that very solid answer :)

Comment: Sure, but I assume he actually has an async task hidden below his pseudocode :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just use then.

```
function Foobar() {
  this.foo = function() {
    var self = this;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      console.log('foo');
      resolve(self);
    });
  };
  this.bar = function() {
    var self = this;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      console.log('bar');
      resolve(self);
    });
  }
}

new Foobar().foo().then(function(foobar) { return foobar.bar(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a handy `.call` method that allows you to call a method on the resolved value.  I've found it pretty handy in a few cases: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#callstring-propertyname--dynamic-arg---promise